# Web Audio API on Windows?

Tags: windows, safari, webkit, web-audio-api

I'm trying to run a [Web Audio API demo](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/convolution-effects.html) using a [nightly build of WebKit](http://nightly.webkit.org/) on Windows.

The demo won't run, and the console throws an error (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: webkitAudioContext).

Does anyone know if it's currently possible to use the Web Audio API with WebKit nightly builds on windows?  If so, what steps do I need to take to make the demos run?  Do I need to set an environment variable, or pass a command line argument to the executable or something?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this question at the moment is "no". It seems that Chrome is the only browser at the moment that supports the Web Audio API on Windows. Safari/WebKit for Windows doesn't support it yet.